# Only 192.168.0.3 can request, but anyone can request /public/file.html

Tags: apache, networking, apache2, request

I have the following virtual host on my development server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/web/example.com/pub
    <Directory /srv/web/example.com/pub>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.0.3
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The `Allow from 192.168.0.3` part is to only allow requests from my workstation machine.

I want to tweak this to allow anyone to request a certain URL:

```
http://example.com/public/file.html
```

How do I change this to allow `/public/file.html` requests to get through from anyone?

Note: `/public/file.html` doesn't actually exist as a file on the server. I redirect all incoming requests through a single index file using `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Belongs to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Every time I post anything to webmasters.stackexchange.com, it gets migrated to server fault. [Including this time](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8500/only-192-168-0-3-can-request-but-anyone-can-request-public-file-html?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only way that I found to fix it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/web/example.com/pub
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/public/file.html" public
    <Directory /srv/web/example.com/pub>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.0.3
        Allow from env=public
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply configuration directives to paths that do not map to the filesystem, you must use the [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) enclosing directive:

```
<Location /public/file.html>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow From All
</Location>
```